# Drawing a pyramid on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to draw this figure on Matlab (without the bubbles)!
[image]

I wrote following code :

```
figure
hold on 
axis equal
axis([0 20 0 10])
n = 20
n = n - 1 

for y = 0:10
for x = (y+1):n
    rectangle('Position',[x y 1 1],'curvature',[0 0],'facecolor',(rand(1,3)))
    pause(0.05)
end
end
```

I get the following figure on executing this code :

[image]

I need help in writing part of the code where the correct figure can be drawn.

Comment: This is a probably better suited to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop on `x` start at the right point but goes to the maximum at every iteration.

Just modify the loop definition `for x = (y+1):n` to `for x = (y+1):n-y` and you'll get the desired result:

```
for y = 0:10
   for x = (y+1):n-y
       rectangle('Position',[x y 1 1],'curvature',[0 0],'facecolor',(rand(1,3)))
       pause(0.05)
   end
end
```

---

edit: according to your comment, you wanted to achieve that by controling `n`, this is also possible but you have to decrement `n` at each iteration of the outer loop, like so:

```
for y = 0:10
   for x = (y+1):n
       rectangle('Position',[x y 1 1],'curvature',[0 0],'facecolor',(rand(1,3)))
       pause(0.001)
   end
   n=n-1 ;
end
```

Comment: why is n-y necessary ? According to me n = 20 and then n = n-1 should have worked alone. and so x = (y+1):n should have been fine as each time n value would be 1 less than previous.

Comment: Well you do not decrement `n` in your loop (there is no `n=n-1` instruction in the loop), so `n` doesn't change value inside the loop and will stay at 10 forever. You cold do it the way you mention, or many other way actually. I just gave you one example which required the least modification of your code.

Comment: @Manahil, I modified the answer to do it your way ;)

Comment: will you please help me in how to alter the code(include n=n-1 in the loop) so that x = (y+1):n can be used as it is.